# How is it that two covariant vectors can be multiplied without one being transposed?

Tags: vectors, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra, index-notation

This [reading](http://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/~dullemond/lectures/tensor/tensor.pdf#page41), without much explanation, claims that given two covariant vectors,

$$\tilde x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\tilde y = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

one has the product

$$x_\mu y_\nu =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\cdot y_1 & x_1\cdot y_2 & x_1\cdot y_3 \\
x_2\cdot y_1 & x_2\cdot y_2 & x_2\cdot y_3 \\
x_3\cdot y_1 & x_3\cdot y_2 & x_3\cdot y_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Having incredibly little background knowledge on this subject, this makes no sense to me. How can $1\times3$ array times a $1\times3$ array yield a $3\times3$ array? Furthermore, this looks just like the product of a covector and a contravector to me.

Could someone shed some light on what’s going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its achieved by forming [**tensor product**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) of two covector. The tensor product can be thought as generalization of outer product of vectors. Suppose we have a vector space $V$ with its dual space $V^*$, the elements $x \in V^*$ is a linear map 
$$
x : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.
$$

If we have two covectors $\tilde{x},\tilde{y} \in V^*$ where in terms of basis we write them as $\tilde{x} = x_{\mu} \varepsilon^{\mu}$ and $\tilde{y} = y_{\mu}\varepsilon^{\mu}$ (with $\varepsilon^{\mu}$ is the dual basis of $V^*$), their tensor product $\tilde{x} \otimes \tilde{y}$ is $(0,2)$-covariant tensor 
$$
\tilde{x} \otimes \tilde{y} : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
defined as
\begin{align}
(\tilde{x} \otimes \tilde{y}) (v,w) &= \tilde{x}(v) \tilde{y}(w) \\
&= x_{\mu} \varepsilon^{\mu}(v) \, y_{\nu} \varepsilon^{\nu}(w) \\
&= x_{\mu}  y_{\nu}  \, \varepsilon^{\mu}(v)\varepsilon^{\nu}(w) \qquad \text{for all} \, v,w \in V
\end{align}
so in components, we write as $\tilde{x} \otimes \tilde{y} = x_{\mu}y_{\nu} \, \varepsilon^{\mu} \otimes \varepsilon^{\nu}$. We can easily verify that $\tilde{x} \otimes \tilde{y}$  is a multilinear map (i.e $\tilde{x} \otimes \tilde{y}$ is a tensor), and the collection
$$
\{ \varepsilon^{\mu} \otimes \varepsilon^{\nu} \mid  \mu,\nu = 1,2,3 \}
$$
is a basis for the tensor space $(0,2)$.
Your $3\times 3$ array above is the components of this tensor. The author in your article above define tensor as an object that transform properly. You can check that if $x_{\mu}$ and $y_{\nu}$ transform as $x'_{\alpha} = B_{\alpha}^{\mu}x_{\mu}$ and $y'_{\beta} = B_{\beta}^{\nu} y_{\nu}$ and  if you define a new object $t_{\mu\nu} = x_{\mu}y_{\nu}$, then this object transform properly as 
$$
t'_{\alpha \beta} = x'_{\alpha}y'_{\beta} = B_{\alpha}^{\mu}x_{\mu} B_{\beta}^{\nu} y_{\nu} = B_{\alpha}^{\mu}B_{\beta}^{\nu} x_{\mu} y_{\nu} =  B_{\alpha}^{\mu}B_{\beta}^{\nu} t_{\mu\nu} .
$$ 
We can form any tensor product of any two (or more) tensor (of any type) by the same way (look for example [P. Szekeres](https://books.google.co.id/books/about/A_Course_in_Modern_Mathematical_Physics.html?id=CH2JQ2Jc1ksC&redir_esc=y) or [Lee's Smooth Manifold](https://books.google.co.id/books/about/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds.html?id=eqfgZtjQceYC&redir_esc=y) for more details).

However, based on the approach of the text above, you dont really need to know what is tensor product to know that $t_{\mu\nu}=x_{\mu}y_{\nu}$ is a tensor. As long as the object transform properly (even if the construction is look strange to you as $t_{\mu\nu}$ above), you can be sure that its a tensor. This is the kind of approach that the author follow.