# Can 2 contravariant vectors be multiplied by a tensor product?

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, tensors

How can you do the tensor product between the basis covectors $ \epsilon^i $ & $ \epsilon^j  $  to result in $ \epsilon^i \otimes \epsilon^j  $   when $ \epsilon^i $ & $ \epsilon^j  $ have only contravariant indices?

I did check this-
[How is it that two covariant vectors can be multiplied without one being transposed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531992/how-is-it-that-two-covariant-vectors-can-be-multiplied-without-one-being-transpo/2532066)

But there it was assumed $ \epsilon^i \otimes \epsilon^j  $ to be true by default.

Comment: If you're in a purely calculating mood, taking the product of $\epsilon^i$ and $\epsilon^j$ doesn't pose a problem at all. You get a doubly contravariant tensor $E^{ij}$, where as real numbers, $E^{12} = \epsilon^1\cdot \epsilon^2$, and so on, and that's it. So I guess you want a more conceptually angled answer.

Comment: Maybe you could explain your background a little more, like if you come from physics, how you would define a covector, something like that. Just so we know where you stand.

Answer (score 0):

If $\varepsilon^i$ are linear functionals (a.k.a covectors), that is, 
$\varepsilon^i:V\to\mathbb R$
are linear transformations, then the
$\varepsilon^i\otimes\varepsilon^j$ are bilinear transformation
$$\varepsilon^i\otimes\varepsilon^j:V\times V\to\mathbb R$$
defined by
$$\varepsilon^i\otimes\varepsilon^j(v,w)=\varepsilon^i(v)\varepsilon^j(w).$$
Linearity of $\varepsilon^i$ implies the bi-linearity of the $\varepsilon^i\otimes\varepsilon^j$.  In general $\varepsilon^i\otimes\varepsilon^j$ is different from $\varepsilon^j\otimes\varepsilon^i$ and the $\varepsilon^j\otimes\varepsilon^j$
make sense.